# Toast.show() not showing the message in Emulator

Tags: android, kotlin, toast

This seems to work on Android 6 Marshmallow device Xiaomi Redmi 3S.
Seems like an emulator problem, but it isn't really misbehaving in any other sense.

I am a beginner in Android development and don't know much.
I have already confirmed that notifications for my app is ON.

Specs:
API Level : Android 4.4 (KitKat)

Android Studio version: 3.6.4

Emulator: Pixel XL API 28

All I attempted to do was a toast message would pop up telling how many times the button has been clicked.

Here's the MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var greetingCount = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btnToastMessage.setOnClickListener {
            val suffix = when (++greetingCount) {
                1 -> "st"
                2 -> "nd"
                3 -> "rd"
                else -> "th"
            }
            val greetingMsg = "Welcome for the $greetingCount$suffix time(s)!"
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, greetingMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Log.i(".MainActivity", "Clicked Button")
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="30dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHelloWorld"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.314" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnToastMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtHelloWorld"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.49" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Is log printing ? also just cross check if correct synthetic is imported

Comment: This should work, I don't understand why its not working

Comment: Shouldn't you do `findViewById` for button?

Comment: I tested your code and it worked on my Android 10 emulator, try it with the android 10 emulator.

Comment: @ManoharReddy Yes the log print is working.

Comment: @AhmerMH I tried via the findViewById() function too. Same failed result.

Comment: does it work on other devices ?

Comment: @Saba I am running this on Android 9 emulator, so not too far off.

Comment: @ManoharReddy Surprisingly yes. Just tested it on my Xiaomi Redmi 3S (Android 6 Marhsmallow). Going to add this in the question.

Comment: @VivekYadav There might be an issue with `emulator` have you tried with other `emulators`, I am able to see `toast` for my application with same `emulator`. Just for the sake of testing replace `this@MainActivity` with `applicationContext` and try once.

Comment: @Keshav1234 Nope. Still the same result.

Comment: @Keshav1234 I have tried it on a smarphone, but not on a different emulator..

Comment: @VivekYadav might be a issue with emulator I feel you need not worrk until it works on a real device

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Didn't know this could be done, but wiping data and cold-booting the device fixed it.

Comment: For those that aren't aware (I was not), "cold-booting" the device means shutting down the emulator app andr restarting it.

Comment: cold-booting from the avd manager solved the problem for me. i didn't have to wipe the data.

Comment: Yes, that worked!

Answer (score 4):

Following are the steps you can follow (because I too got stuck):

- Try restarting and cleaning your emulator device.
- OR
- You can run the app on your physical (android) device by setting the USB Debugging
  option to True.

Comment: Please read the question throughout, I've mentioned that I've tried the aforementioned but to no avail. Fortunately this thread had already been resolved around 1 year ago and I've ticked the helpful response that you can check out if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but my issue got fixed :)