# Toast.makeText().show(); does not show up

Tags: java, android, xml

I have configured Toast.makeText with all of the necessary parameters inside for a simple program that I wrote.

In my program there's two image views + image buttons that swap to a different background image after a click. I set a condition to push a toast notification whenever the background images of the buttons are the same.

Here's my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.projectName;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //declare ImageButton here
    ImageButton imageButton;
    ImageButton imageButton2;

    //variable for toggling state
    boolean isClicked = false;
    boolean isClicked2 = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize ImageButton here
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.image_1);
        imageButton2 = findViewById(R.id.image_2);

    }

    public void foo(View v) { //first image View

        if (isClicked) {

            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageFileName);

            //reverse button state
            isClicked = false;
        } else {
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageFileName2);

            //reverse button state
            isClicked = true;
        }

        if (isClicked == isClicked2) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void bar(View v) { //second image view

        if (isClicked2) {

            imageButton2.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageFileName);

            //reverse button state
            isClicked2 = false;
        } else {
            imageButton2.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageFileName2);

            //reverse button state
            isClicked2 = true;
        }

        if (isClicked == isClicked2) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}
```

Here's my activity_main.xml file where the imageButtons are defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- android:background stores imageFileName.png -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_1"
            android:tag="12"
            android:onClick="foo"
            android:background="@drawable/imageFileName"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp">
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_2"
            android:tag="13"
            android:onClick="bar"
            android:background="@drawable/imageFileName2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp">
        </ImageButton>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the virtual device output:

[image: virtual device output w/o toast notif]

Since the two images are the same, a toast notification should show up.

Comment: have you tried to debug your application with breakpoints or logs ? is `isClicked == isClicked2` ever true ?

Comment: `if (isClicked && isClicked2)`

Comment: does this only happen on Emulator?   If so this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277598/toast-show-not-showing-the-message-in-emulator

Comment: @a_local_nobody I debugged with Log.v and the isClicked == isClicked2 does go through. But the toast does not go through

Comment: @blackapps (isClicked && isClicked2) also worked, but the toast notif still didn't show up

Comment: @CSmith closed out the emulator and ran it again but the issue still persists

Comment: `Since the two images are the same, a toast notification should show up.` Equal images has noting to do with it. Only if two booleans are true at the same time. Please just put a Toast() in foo() and bar() that always will be called. Also you did not tell if the background changes. Also you did not tell if the Toast is called and then does not show up. Please put sone Log.d() statements in your functions to examine behaviour. Debug!
`

Comment: use `isClicked = !isClicked` instead of that if-else.

Comment: `closed out the emulator` What is closing out an emulater? You are supposed to cold boot it i read.

Comment: @blackapps cold booting worked! Feel free to write up an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Not i but @CSmith told you to cold boot in link of the third comment here. I read it and i thought you did not.. So thank and invite him.

Comment: @CSmith feel free to put your answer in the answer format and I'll accept it

Comment: It's more appropriate to close this question as a duplicate, nonetheless I'm glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Could be the Toast color is white and not visible, try

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
TextView v = (TextView)toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
v.setTextColor(Color.RED);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **`Android Notifications`** are Turned **`ON`** for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing the context when you call Toast.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```